# Any "directory chooser" with JSF?

Tags: jsf, directory

I want to know if there's any kind of "directory chooser" in JSF. I'm intending to get a directory and make some treatments on contained files. Thanks.

Comment: Do you want to select a directory on server machine or on client machine?

Answer (score 0):

The case "to choose a directory" through the web browser on the client is almost not possible. It's absolutely possible to choose a directory on the server or over a protocol which supports that.